# going to for an already fully planned decision

Tags: future-tense

> In two days M **is going to** camp with her group. They planned it all month

Why "going to" instead of "is camping" because it has been already arranged, it took one month so it has been fully arranged

Comment: The syntax of your example context is potentially ambiguous, in that *[going to] **camp*** could be seen as a *[future] **verb*** construction (as per *The rain is **going to stop***), or the last two words could be seen as a *preposition + location* (as per *I'm **going to London***). Personally, my natural reaction is to see it as the latter (that's to say, "camp" is a noun usage representing the place M and her group are going to). But this is really just *syntax* - the actual *meaning* is effectively the same whichever stylistic choice you make.

Answer (score 1):

The **camp** is possibly a specific venue and not some vague location where you "go camping".

In this case **camp** could be the [American custom](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/summer_camp), and **camp** is a noun and not a verb, because **camp** is the *destination* where M is going.

> In two days M is going to [summer] camp with her group.

Answer (score 0):

If you have been taught that "be going to" is only used for *uncertain* future events, you have been taught wrong.

"Be going to" is a standard way in English to indicate a *future* activity.  Future activities are always *uncertain*, since no one can predict what will actually happen.  Just saying "it's been planned for a month" doesn't make it any more certain.  You have use the context to judge how certain the speaker is of the event.

Consider a wedding, for example.  A wedding ceremony is, as you say, a "fully planned" event.  It's not something you (normally) change the date of, or call off, at the last minute.  Without further information, all of the following sound more or less equally *certain* (because it's only a month beforehand):

> We **are getting** married next month.
>
> We **are going to get** married next month.
>
> We **will get** married next month.

Still, you can always qualify.

> Alice: Chris and I **are getting** married next month, but we still have to find a venue for the ceremony.
>   Ben:  So you might not get married?
>   Alice:  No, no.  **It's going to happen**.  Everything **will come** together, you'll see.